# Generate random number with quantity

Tags: c#

I have questions how can I set the quantity of numbers in the result box based on the selected value in dropdown

[image]

This is my code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
{
    string totalListNumber = "";

    for (double x = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text); x <= Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text); x++)
    {
       

        totalListNumber += x + "\n";
        

    }
    
    TextBox3.Text = totalListNumber;
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to create a random number between your two values.

```
    System.Random roll = new Random();
    int nextRandom = roll.Next(minValue, maxValue);
```

Your combo box has an event called SelectedIndexChanged that will trigger when the user changes your combo selection.

In your SelectedIndexChanged code you should then put something like:

```
private void cmbQuantities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Random roll = new Random();
    int nextRandom;

    // turn the two textBoxes into two doubles minValue and maxValue
    if ((double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out double minValue) == false) || (double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out double maxValue) == false)) return;

    // get the number of items to display or exit if it is not a valid number (return)
    if (int.TryParse(cmbQuantities.Text, out int randomsToDisplay) == false) return;

    string totalListNumber = String.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < randomsToDisplay; i++)
    {
        nextRandom = roll.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        
        totalListNumber += nextRandom.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    TextBox3.Text = totalListNumber;
}
```

There are a lot of other boosts you should do (such as using a listView etc), but this will get you what you want.

You should also try looking at using a datasource for the comboBoxQuantity that has an int value and string description so that selecting the combo item gets you the quantity value as an int automatically (or even just use a textbox!)

**Avoiding duplicate numbers**

As the Random class will produce duplicate numbers you will need to store your random rolls in a list and then check the list every time a new number is rolled.

The HashSet class allows fast lookups by a key (your random number in this case).

So:

```
private void cmbQuantities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Random roll = new Random();
    int nextRandom;
    HashSet<int> rolledRandoms = new HashSet<int>();

    // turn the two textBoxes into two doubles minValue and maxValue
    if ((double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out double minValue) == false) || (double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out double maxValue) == false)) return;

    // get the number of items to display or exit if it is not a valid number (return)
    if (int.TryParse(cmbQuantities.Text, out int randomsToDisplay) == false) return;

    string totalListNumber = String.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < randomsToDisplay; i++)
    {
        nextRandom = roll.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        // keep rolling until the nextRandom value is not in the rolledRandoms list
        while (rolledRandoms.ContainsKey(nextRandom))
            nextRandom = roll.Next(minValue, maxValue);

        rolledRandoms.Add(nextRandom);
        totalListNumber += nextRandom.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    TextBox3.Text = totalListNumber;
}
```

Comment: sir is it possible that there will be no duplicate numbers?

Comment: Added code to remove duplicates. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0 for more info on how to use HashSets.

Comment: sir i try to add higher numbers such as 362192794304 and the result is all like this -2,147,483,648 what happen?

Comment: The largest number in C# is represented in binary (1s and 0s) as 
111111111111..[lots of 1s]..11111111111110 
with the last bit being 0 for positive numbers and 1 for negative numbers. Your number is bigger than the maximum so it has flicked the 0 bit to a 1 and turned the number negative.
if you want bigger numbers than max you need to look at some maths and make your own Random number generator.
btw: Any particular reason you want Random numbers that big?